# iOS6 redirect to secure pages with invalid SSL certificate not working

Tags: ios6, mobile-safari, moovweb

I have a page which takes users from an insecure page to a secure page via a redirect, but it is not working on iOS6 Safari. The secure page has an invalid certificate as this is a testing environment, but on iOS5 and Android 4 I am given the option to accept the invalid certificate. However, on iOS6 the page just seems unresponsive.

The flow would look something like

Go to http://www.mydomain.com/mypage
click link which returns a 302 to https://www.mydomain.com/mypage

Desired result: Get option to accept the invalid certificate

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Comment: Is this a bug in iOS6? Or, perhaps, a new security feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply visit the https version of the page first and accept the certificate.

Alternative you can create a Root Certificate, install it on your phone via a profile, and then use that Root CA to create a SSL certificate for your testing domain.